# Utilisation d'un verbe à l'infinitif comme nom

Tags: expressions, verbes, infinitif

Je suis récemment tombé sur l'expression ***au sortir de l'école***, signifiant *à la sortie de l'école* (dans le sens *à la fin des études*).

Je me posais les questions suivantes :

1. Cette expression est-elle du bon français, de l'argot, une expression régionale ?
2. Peut-on construire un nom avec quelques autres verbes ? avec tous les autres verbes (sauf la sempiternelle exception) ?

Par exemple, serait-il correct de dire

> Il a eu beau se déguiser, je l'ai reconnu au manger. (à sa façon de manger)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Sortir* possède dans le TLF une [entrée spécifique](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sortir//1) pour le substantif, et ce n'est pas le cas de tous les autres verbes. Je pense que ça répond aux deux questions :

1. C'est du bon français, bien que peut-être un peu vieillot.
2. Ce n'est possible qu'avec certains verbes.

Note: [*Manger*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/manger//1) admet aussi une substantivation mais sa définition correspond plutôt à de la nourriture ou à un repas, et pas vraiment à une façon de manger. Le dernier exemple me semble donc limite.